# C++ реализация push_front для произвольного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Только начинаю изучать ООП и столкнулся с проблемой реализации push_front для произвольного класса за О(1). Скорее всего, ошибка лежит на поверхности, но мне пока не хватает опыта ее диагностировать. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
У меня есть вот такой произвольный класс:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T, size_t N>
class MyClass {
    static const size_t None = -1;
    size_t msz; // текущий размер
    size_t mbeg; // индекс первого элемента
    T data[N]; // массив с данными
    T& GetValue(size_t i) {
        return data[mbeg + i];
    }
public:
    MyClass() : msz(0), mbeg(None) {
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass& c) = default;

    ~MyClass() = default;

    bool is_full() const {
        return msz == N;
    }

    bool is_empty() const {
        return msz == 0;
    }

    void push_front(const T& value) {
        if (!is_full()) { // добавляем элементы только если есть место
            if (mbeg == None) {
                mbeg = N - 1;
            }
            else {
                mbeg = mbeg - 1; // сдвигаем номер первого элемента
            }
            GetValue(0) = value; // присваиваем значение первому элементу
            msz++; // увеличиваем размер
        }
    }
    void pop_front() {
        if (!is_empty()) {
            if (msz == 0) {
                mbeg = None;
             }
             else {
                mbeg = mbeg + 1;
             }
            --msz;
        }
    }
    void Print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << data[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    size_t Size() {
        return msz;
    }
};
```

Всё бы ничего. Потом пишу функцию main() для проверки:

```
int main() {
    MyClass<int, 3> v;
    v.push_front(1);
    v.push_front(2);
    v.push_front(3);
    v.Print(); // Вывод 3 2 1
    v.pop_front();
    v.Print(); // Вывод 3 2 , а ожидался 2 1
    return 0;
}
```

При применении метода `pop_front` удаляется последний элемент, а не первый. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: `bool is _empty` у вас пробел стоит между `is` и `_empty` исправьте пожалуйста. И приведите код функции `Print`. Так же функции `Get`. `m_beg` и `m_begin` идентификатор не найден вообще. Выложите уж полностью весь класс)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков исправлено

Comment: Выложите весь код вашего класса, чтобы можно было запустить у себя!

Comment: Почитайте: [mcve]

Comment: @ПавелЕриков сейчас всё запускается (запутался в своих версиях)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в функции `Print`. Вы выводите элементы с `0` по `Size() - 1`, хотя если удалите первый элемент, то ваши данные будут располагаться с `1` по `Size() - 1` индексы.

То есть вам нужно выводить ваши данные таким образом:

```
std::cout << data[mbeg + i] << " ";
```